# Jenkins Pipeline failed for Android

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, kapt

Jenkins pipeline project build failed with error message

```
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWkCL.png)

Answer (score 3):

Seems the problem is not from `jenkins`.
In error message i notice the exact problem comes from "`annotations processing`"

```
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Add `kotlin kapt` plugin in your app build `gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Make sure you have added `kotlin-gradle-plugin` class path in root `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Replace `annotationProcessor` into `kapt`

**Instead of**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

**Should be**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This message comes from **app: 'annotationProcessor'** process

1> Add the below line in your `project:build.gradle`

```
plugins{
    id ("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

2> Add the below line `under plugins in your app: build.gradle` file.

```
id ("com.google.devtools.ksp")
```

3> Final step add the below line under `dependencies tag` in your `app: build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
ksp 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```